# Python submodule internal references -- are they just crazy?

Tags: python, module, package

Apologies in advange for the newbie question. I can't get my head around this, and the docs don't help!

Consider the following directory structure:

```
spam.py
foo     / __init__.py
          ham.py
          eggs.py
```

with the following code:

```
# __init__.py
# blank

# ham.py
print( "got ham!" )

# eggs.py
print( "got eggs, importing ham!" )
import foo.ham
```

Now, if I `import foo.eggs` inside `spam.py` (!), the right thing happens and all the module references work.

#### BUT

If I try and execute `eggs.py` directly, I get an `ImportError: No module named foo.ham`! If I change the `foo.ham` imports to just `ham`, the right thing happens... but then I can't `import foo.eggs`!

So, how do I develop `eggs`? If I use 'undotted' references, I can develop fine, but can't try it out because I can't `import` the module! If I use the full `foo.ham` reference, I can import the package, but can't execute the submodule for development purposes!

Is this just a glitch with Python's packaging architecture? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: When you have `import foo.ham` in `eggs.py` what happens when you execute `eggs.py` from the parent directory: `python foo/eggs.py`?

Comment: Which version of python are you using, it works for me in 2.6.4 when I only put import ham in eggs.py.

Comment: @Matt: another `ImportError`, this time in `foo\eggs.py` instead of in `eggs.py`.

@Eric: I'm using 3.1.2 but have tried it in 2.4.3 as well, no luck. Are you sure you've set up the files right?

Comment: Is the directory containing `foo` listed in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: No, but it shouldn't have to be: "In fact, such references are so common that the import statement first looks in the containing package before looking in the standard module search path."

Comment: I also believe foo doesn't have to be on the python path. I'm pretty sure I got the files right. I'm on windows at work though, maybe it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm on Windows as well... which way are you testing it? I.e., have you got `import foo.ham` or `import ham`?

Comment: __init__.py: empty, 
eggs.py: print( "got eggs, importing ham!" )
import ham
ham.py: print "got ham !"
spam.py: from foo import eggs but import foo.eggs also work.

spam.py is beside foo folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work: Here is the directory structure:

```
~/test/kl% ls -R
.:
foo  spam.py

./foo:
eggs.py  eggs.pyc  ham.py  ham.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

Here are the file contents:

```
~/test/kl% cat spam.py 
import foo.eggs

~/test/kl% cd foo/
~/test/kl/foo% cat eggs.py
print( "got eggs, importing ham!" )
import ham
```

We can import ham from spam.py, and foo/eggs.py:

```
~/test/kl% python spam.py 
got eggs, importing ham!
got ham!
```

A useful rule to remember is that when you say `python script.py`, the directory containing `script.py` is added to the beginning of `sys.path`, the directories searched for modules. That's why `python spam.py` works without changing `PYTHONPATH`.

```
~/test/kl% python foo/eggs.py
got eggs, importing ham!
got ham!
```

Here, ~/test/kl/foo is added to the `sys.path`. That's okay, because `eggs.py` tries to `import ham`. Since `ham.py` resides in `~/test/kl/foo` which is in `sys.path`, Python finds it just fine.

```
~/test/kl% cd foo
~/test/kl/foo% python eggs.py
got eggs, importing ham!
got ham!
```

The directory ~/test/kl was not in my PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Ugh. Still doesn't work for me, I wonder if it's a Linux thing? I don't have access to Linux atm unfortunately...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't modify your `spam.py` while writing this? I have literally checked my files ten times, and `python spam.py` does not work.

Comment: @katrielalex: I just checked again. The file contents are as I've posted.

Comment: You might want to try removing any old .pyc, .pyw files.

Answer (score 1):

The parent directory for foo needs to be in the python's path:

```
$ ls foo
eggs.py  ham.py  ham.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
$ python foo/ham.py
got ham!
$ python foo/eggs.py
got eggs, importing ham!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/eggs.py", line 2, in <module>
    import foo.ham
ImportError: No module named foo.ham
$ PYTHONPATH=. python foo/eggs.py
got eggs, importing ham!
got ham!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python's packaging architecture. Normally a module can import modules either from current directory with dotted reference, either from $PYTHONPATH directory.
You should understand that a module reference is just relative path to this module. So... an interpreter can't import any module that's not found on file system.

Comment: I quote the docs: The submodules often need to refer to each other. For example, the surround module might use the echo module. In fact, such references are so common that the import statement first looks in the containing package before looking in the standard module search path... see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: The quote from the docs ("the import statement first looks in the containing package before looking in the standard module search path") is only in the Python 2 docs. It is not supported in Python 3. That confused me for a while until I realized. In 3, you have to use a relative import like `from . import ham`